# Ошибка извлечения из архива «installer://preview.qt.tools.qtcreator/4.6.84-0-201807050557preview-qtcreator.7z»: недостаточно памяти

Tags: qt, qt5, память

В данном случае демонстрирую на примере preview 5.11.2 но абсолютно аналогичная ошибка вываливается и на 5.11.1, до этого стояла 5.10.1. Всё было хорошо, решил обновиться, но в результате остался вообще без всего.

> Ошибка во время процесса установки (preview.qt.tools.qtcreator): Ошибка извлечения из архива «installer://preview.qt.tools.qtcreator/4.6.84-0-201807050557preview-qtcreator.7z»: недостаточно памяти

Повторить не помогает, при пропустить вываливаются и дальше такие ошибки. На диске порядка 15 гигов свободно, оперы тоже хватает. Ubuntu 18.04.1 x64 
Спасибо если кто знает где собака зарыта

Далее появляется ещё одна

> Ошибка во время процесса установки (qt.qt5.5112.gcc_64): Не удалось исполнить (неожиданный код завершения: 3): «/opt/Qt//Tools/QtCreator/libexec/qtcreator/sdktool addQt --id qt.qt5.5112.gcc_64 --name Qt %{Qt:Version} GCC 64bit --type Qt4ProjectManager.QtVersion.Desktop --qmake /opt/Qt/5.11.2/gcc_64/bin/qmake»

Comment: а чем системный Qt из реп не устраивает?

Comment: MaintenanceTool запускаешь от рута?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, вопрос ведь не в том, чем системный Qt не устраивает, а в том, как установить Qt!

Comment: @misdeed, т.к. в вопросе OP явно не обозначил, что он сознательно хочет установить кьют из sdk вместо репазитариев, то лучше лишний раз уточнить, что он знает, что делает...